How do I use a loop to update the progress of my entire code in python using a progress bar
I have a code that pulls data from mysql database using python mysql connector and I want to create a progress bar in python using tkinter that shows query execution progress.
I have created a loop that calculates how long it will take for the query to execute but I discovered that the loop runs separately while the other parts of the code runs separately.
I expect the loop to run concurrently with other parts of the code. I don't know if I am doing this the right way, any help will really be appreciated.
Below is the code I used
from tkinter import ttk
import time
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import *
import mysql.connector as sql
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

db_connection = sql.connect(
    host='',
    database='',
    user='',
    password='',  sql_mode='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION' 
)

def query():
    total_rows, df2 = biometrics()
    progress_bar['maximum'] = total_rows  # Set to 100 for percentage completion
    for index, row in df2.iterrows():
            
        # Update the progress bar value
        progress_bar['value'] = index + 1
        
        # Calculate the percentage of completion
        percentage = ((index + 1) / total_rows) * 100
        
        # Update the status label with the current percentage
        status_label.config(text=f"Counting rows to process... {index + 1}/{total_rows} ({percentage:.2f}%)")
                
        # Update the GUI to reflect changes
        root.update_idletasks()
        
        # Simulate time-consuming task
        time.sleep(0.0001)
        
           
    db_cursor = db_connection.cursor()
    db_cursor.execute(""" #time consuming query here """)


# Creating Main Window
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("QUERY PROGRESS")
root.geometry("650x400")
root.config(bg="#f0f0f0")

MY_button = tk.Button(root, text="CONNECT & GENERATE LINE LIST...", command=query, font=("Helvetica", 14), bg="#4caf50", fg="#ffffff")
convert_button.pack(pady=5)

progress_bar = ttk.Progressbar(root, orient='horizontal', length=300, mode='indeterminate')
progress_bar.pack(pady=15)

# Label for percentage and progress messages
status_label = tk.Label(root, text="0%", font=('Helvetica', 12))
status_label.pack(pady=5)



To run loop concurrently you need to put it into separate thread or process using threading or multiprocessing

Instead time.sleep. You will need this root.after(...)

As already mentioned, you should not use sleep but after, otherwise you will block the mainloop. If you only simulate the required time, how do you intend to ensure that your query is not finished much earlier or later than your progressbar? I suggest you either try to split the query into smaller chunks and increasing the progressbar inbetween or just use the indeterminate mode to display the loading. You could start the latter before the query and end it afterwards.

What does biometrics() do? It looks like it returns a dataframe, so what is the purpose of db_cursor.execute() if data has already been returned by biometrics() and the progress bar has been updated completely?

Typo error MY_button = tk.Button(...) MY_button = tk.Button(pady=15). Should be MY_button.pack(pady=5)

@mugiseyebrows thanks for your feedback and sorry I am responding now
However, I am pretty new in using python and I just want the progress of my query to display on the tkinter interface
I don't know if you can modify my code to do this as each row of my query is being executed
this will be highly appreciated
Thank you.

@toyotaSupra I will try using root.after(...) to see if I will have a better output
thank you

@Jan_B thank you so much for your feedback
you are on point, concurrency between query execution time and the loop I am using has really been a think of concern to me.
I don't know if you can modify my code to suit your suggestion even if I have to fall back to indeterminate mode. It has not been long I started using python

@acw1668 biometrics is just a function that houses total_rows to be processed which I unpacked in the query function. it is a very light query that gives me an idea of rows to be processed before the main query is executed.
can you modify my code to show progress of the main query
I feel I am doing this the wrong way.

@toyotaSupra your feedback is duly noted
